# Dark theme on supported websites?

Tags: themes

Just like on Windows, when you visit some websites, they check if you have dark theme enabled in the OS and switch their website to dark theme. Is it possible on Elementary OS? (For eg, the chrome://settings page gets darkened if dark mode is enabled in Windows)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the Dark Reader extension for web browser.

https://darkreader.org/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).